# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre paso de variables por valor y por referencia?

Tags: paso-por-valor, paso-por-referencia, lenguaje-agnóstico

El título es explícito. ¿Qué diferencia fundamental o fundamentales hay entre estos métodos al momento de definir las funciones o métodos?

**Importante:** A pesar de ser una pregunta muy similar a [esta en stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373419/1065197), no intenta ser una traducción de ninguna de sus respuestas.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/373419/1065197

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Cuando es por **valor**, la información de la variable se almacenan en una dirección de memoria diferente al recibirla en la funcion, por lo tanto si el valor de esa variable cambia no afecta la variable original, solo se modifica dentro del contexto de la función.

Cuando es por **referencia**, la variable que se recibe como parámetro en la función apunta exactamente a la misma dirección de memoria que la variable original por lo que si dentro de la función se modifica su valor también se modifica la variable original.

Tal y como se explica en este gif.

[image: gif explicativo]

Answer (score 7):

La esencia de la diferencia corresponde a la libertad (o restricción) que existe sobre el parámetro de la función o método.

El paso por valor se refiere a que se pasa **una copia** del valor del parámetro desde la función/método cliente. Al ser una copia, los cambios realizados directamente en la función/método sobre el valor del parámetro **no serán** reflejados al terminar la ejecución de la función/método.

El paso por referencia se refiere a que se pasa **el mismo** valor del parámetro desde la función/método cliente. Al ser el mismo valor, los cambios realizados directamente en la función/método sobre el valor del parámetro **serán** reflejados al terminar la ejecución de la función/método.

Por poner un ejemplo sobre esto, imagina un documento físico que tienes en tus manos. Este documento lo pasas **por valor** cuando primero sacas una copia del documento y la copia la entregas a un compañero. Si el compañero, por algún accidente, mancha este documento, tu documento original no se verá afectado puesto que el compañero ha trabajado sobre una copia. Por el contrario, al pasar **por referencia** el documento significa que entregas el documento original a tu compañero, y si lo quema, crea uno nuevo con un contenido totalmente distinto y te lo devuelve, entonces ahora lo que te ha entregado será **el** documento y el documento original se perdió :(.

De manera más técnica, se puede ver este ejemplo en C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pasoPorValor(int i) {
    i = 50;
}
void pasoPorReferencia(int *i) {
    (*i) = -10;
}
int main() {
    int i = 10;
    pasoPorValor(i);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    //&i significa que se pasa la referencia de la variable i
    pasoPorReferencia(&i);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Resultado de la impresión:

```
10
-10
```

Es importante conocer si el lenguaje de programación utilizado permite el paso de variables por valor y/o por referencia. Por ejemplo, Java y Scala **no permiten** pasar variables por referencia. C, C++, C#, Visual Basic, entre otros, **sí** permiten ambos tipos de paso de variables.

**Importante:** No se debe confundir paso de referencia con paso de valor de la referencia. Este último significa que se pasa una copia de la referencia, sin embargo permite la edición del estado de la referencia referenciada por el parámetro (valga la redundancia).

Comment: C no permite el paso por referencia, se puede decir que "simula" paso por referencia cuando se le envía un puntero, pero si tratas de modificar el puntero (no la variable a la que apunta) los cambios no van a afectar el puntero fuera de la función.