# JS: El valor de un parámetro en una función se puede modificar?

Tags: javascript, poo, funciones, variables, scope

aquí tengo un ejemplo:

```
function ejemplo(parametro){

        parametro = parametro.split(", ");

        return parametro;

}
```

Si hago lo siguiente estoy modificando el valor del parámetro o estoy definiendo una nueva variable en el ámbito de la función?

En el caso de que se esté definiendo una nueva variable en que ámbito sería? En mi caso tengo dicha función dentro de un método de un objeto.

Muchas gracias por adelantado! (:

Comment: ¿ Lenguaje ? ¿ Tipo de la variable ? Varia mucho de unos casos a otros.

Comment: Ups, es cierto, lo he olvidado! Es javascript, un saludo!

Comment: @AdriàFàbrega lo vas a modificar según que sea, si `parametro` es un tipo primitivo, no se va a modificar, pero si en cambio, es un `array` o un objeto, si!

Answer (score 1):

En Javascript el parámetro siempre se pasa por valor. Dicho esto, si el parámetro es un String o un Number solo se modifica dentro de la función ya que se trata de una primitiva mientras que si el parámetro es un Object o un Array, en cambio, el valor pasado es una referencia y podemos modificar propiedades o valores dentro del Object o Array pero no la referencia en sí misma

Pongo aquí mi traducción de [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/323149) respuesta en inglés que explica mejor lo que acabo de decir

```js
function cambiarParametros(a, b, c)
{
  a = a * 10;
  b.item = "cambiado";
  c = {item: "cambiado"};
}

var num = 10;
var obj1 = {item: "original"};
var obj2 = {item: "original"};

cambiarParametros(num, obj1, obj2);

console.log(num);
console.log(obj1.item);    
console.log(obj2.item);
```

El código produce la siguiente salida:

```
10
cambiado
original
```

Lo que quiere decir que el primer parámetro solo cambia de valor dentro de la función al ser una primitiva, el segundo es un objeto y cambia una de sus propiedades pero el tercero, siendo un objeto, no cambia porque se intenta cambiar el valor de la referencia creando un objeto nuevo que no persiste fuera de la función

Answer (score 0):

lo que preguntas, es un tema bastante amplio, existen dos tipos de pasajes de variables a una función.

Me remito a [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1493/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-paso-de-variables-por-valor-y-por-referencia) respuesta para citar:

> Cuando es por **valor**, la información de la variable se almacenan en una
>   dirección de memoria diferente al recibirla en la funcion, por lo
>   tanto si el valor de esa variable cambia no afecta la variable
>   original, solo se modifica dentro del contexto de la función.
>
> Cuando es por **referencia**, la variable que se recibe como parámetro en
>   la función apunta exactamente a la misma dirección de memoria que la
>   variable original por lo que si dentro de la función se modifica su
>   valor también se modifica la variable original.

Ahora, sabiendo esto, una función en JavaScript los tipos primitivos siempre son recibidos por **valor** en las funciones, mientras que los Array y objetos siempre serán recibidos por **referencia**

Vamos a un ejemplo:

```js
function porValor(variable)
{
  variable = "Nuevo valor!";
}


var variable = "Valor original!";

porValor(variable);

console.log(variable);
```

Como se puede ver, el contenido de `variable` no se ve modificado, ahora vamos al ejemplo de un objeto

```js
function porReferencia(objeto)
{
   objeto.valor = "Nuevo valor!";
}

var objeto = 
{
  valor: "Original"
};

porReferencia(objeto);

console.log(objeto.valor);
```

En este ejemplo, se puede ver como el contenido del objeto `objeto` se ve modificado.

Por último aclarar, que los objetos no pueden ser reasignados dentro de una función, sólo pueden modificarse sus propiedades.

En caso que el objeto sea reasignado (utilizando `=`) el objeto original no será modificado, sino, una copia local dentro del scope de la función

```js
function reAsignar(objeto)
{
 var objeto = 
 {
    valor : "No funciona!"
 };
 console.log(objeto.valor);
}

var objeto = 
{
  valor: "Original"
};

reAsignar(objeto);
console.log(objeto.valor);
```

Espero que quede claro el concepto, saludos

Comment: Yo pensaba que también se pasaban por referencia los objetos pero resulta que no. Mira lo que he puesto a partir de la respuesta en inglés

Comment: @JavierMollá esta bien! técnicamente el objeto pasa como referencia, siempre y cuando no intentes reasignarlo, ahora agrego ese último caso que se me olvidó :D