# ¿Como cambio el valor de un parámetro en una función Java?

Tags: java, c#

Estoy llevando de la mano C# y Java

En C# tengo lo siguiente:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void test(ref int a, int b)
        {
            a = a + b;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 10;
            int b = 10;
            test(ref a, b);

            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Esto me imprime 20.

En Java tengo esto:

```
package test;

public class test1 {

    public static void test(int a, int b) {
        a = a + b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 10;
        int b = 10;
        test(a, b);

        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Esto me imprime 10.

¿Que cambio debo hacer al programa de Java para que me imprima 20? ¿Es posible?

Answer (score 5):

A diferencia de C#, en Java [no se pueden pasar parámetros por referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1493/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-paso-de-variables-por-valor-y-por-referencia), siempre es por valor. Por tanto, el valor de la variable que pasas como parámetro al método no puede ser modificada. La única forma de hacerlo es devolviendo un valor:

```
package test;

public class Test1 {

    public static int test(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 10;
        int b = 10;
        a = test(a, b);

        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Es importante saber que no puedes modificar el valor de la variable `a`, pero si ésta fuera un objeto sí podrías modificar su estado: en el caso de los objetos al pasarse por valor lo que se pasa realmente a los métodos es la dirección de memoria (un puntero) al objeto.

Los tipos primitivos (int, char, float, long...) no son objetos. Sus *wrappers* (Integer, Float, Long) sí son objetos pero, al igual que las instancias de String son inmutables (no se pueden modificar tras crearlas).

Answer (score 1):

A tu método '`test`' conviertelo de `void` a `int` y que retorne '`a`'.

Y en el método principal `main`, en la impresión coloca

```
System.out.println(test(a,b));
```